# How can I get conda to resolve package dependencies in a local channel correctly?

Tags: anaconda, conda, offline

I want to set up anaconda with tensorflow on an offline pc. But I am having trouble installing packages because dependencies are not resolved correctly.

On my online Windows10 pc I've installed anaconda and installed tensorflow in a separate environment. I downloaded all the packages and copied them to the offline Windows10 pc in a win-64 directory and indexed using `conda index`. I added the local directory as a channel to the available channels and have set conda to work offline.

I was able to update the local anaconda version using `conda update conda` from this channel and also to update all the packages available in the local channel. I then proceeded to create a channel with python=3.6.

However, when I then try `conda install tensorflow-gpu` I get the 'PackagesNotFoundError', saying that TF is dependent on other packages:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==1.13.1 -> tensorboard[version='>=1.13.0,<1.14.0'] -> grpcio[version='>=1.6.3'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1,<1.1.2.0a0']
  - tensorflow-gpu -> tensorflow==1.13.1 -> tensorflow-base==1.13.1=gpu_py36h871c8ca_0
```

These packages are available, in the right version and build in the local channel and conda search lists them correctly.

It gets more peculiar:

I can install openssl en grpcio from file in my environment and have installed exactly the same version and build as on my online pc. However, 
if I then try to install tensorflow-base conda gives:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-base=1.13.1 -> grpcio[version='>=1.8.6'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1,<1.1.2.0a0']
```

Eventhough `conda list` lists them correctly (versions 1.16.1 and 1.1.1b) with the same builds as on my online pc.

So: I expected to able install tensorflow with its dependencies from the local package repository but are unable to do so. I also expected to be able to install the dependencies by hand and then be able to install tensorflow 
but I still get `PackagesNotFoundError`.

I do not think this is a Tensorflow specific problem. But I've run out of ideas what to try next.

Any help on how to configure/force conda to install these packages would be greatly appreciated.